# PHP time not now showing PM, only AM

Tags: php, time

I'm putting the current time and date in MySQL using

```
$datecreated = date("Y-m-d, g:i:s A");
```

Then showing it to the user with

```
$datecreated = date('n-j-Y, g:i:s A', strtotime($row['datecreated']));
```

Everything works great, except that the time is always AM.  I've tested this in the morning and afternoon, and still AM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `date("Y-m-d  H:i:s")` (24 hour notation) when writing to the database.
Otherwise the  " PM" (or " AM") part just gets truncated, leaving you with always "AM" situation.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using a `DATETIME` field which stores dates and times in 24-hour format.

You can use the MySQL [NOW](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) function to store current time:

```
INSERT INTO mytable
(mydatefield)
VALUES
(NOW())
```

If you need to do it in PHP, you can do:

```
$datecreated = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

This will store it in 24-hour time format. Then you can use the PHP [date](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function after selecting or the MySQL [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function to format it to 12-hour time.

Comment: Can you explain this specific situation, though?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this issue is due to your date format choosing 12-hour times. Change the lower case g to either "G" (no leading zero) or "H" (with leading zero) as they are both 24 hour formats (0-23), whereas "g" is 12-hour format (0-12).

Comment: The OP thought that `A` would allow for 12-hour time. Whether this is true or not. :)

Comment: Ah, of course.. just spotted the true issue. Now I feel silly :/

Comment: Not bad for your second attempt ;)

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use date("Y-m-d, G:i:s")?

Answer (score 0):

You can also just change your server's clock, instead of waiting till the afternoon to test this.

Answer (score 0):

You should try inserting into MySQL using a 24-hour datetime format. MySQL is probably ignoring your AM/PM in your date string, so everything is saved as AM.

```
$datecreated = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```